# how to enable the numeric keypad in xshell?

Tags: terminal

The numeric keypad seems to be not working in X shell terminal application.

How to enable the numeric keypad.

In google, i found to change the mode to ansi instead of Xterm. But some functionality were missing in ansi.

Answer (score 4):

Set the following settings in X shell

In properties of the given shell:
Go to

```
TERMINAL -> VT MODES  -> INITIAL NUMERIC KEYPAD MODE
```

and select option

```
-> SET TO NORMAL
```

Now your numeric keypad will work as usual.